Why can you skip an Item in ListView.builder but not GridView.builder without leaving holes in Flutter?
For Example see the following ListView and GridView builders:
This is my ListView for example:
ListView.builder(
             
              itemCount: itemList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                if (index % 2 == 0 && index < itemList.length) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      ListElementWidget(data: itemList[index]),
                      (index + 1 < itemList.length)
                          ? Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                              child: ListElementWidget(
                                  data: itemList[index + 1]),
                            )
                          : const SizedBox(
                              width: 0,
                            ),
                    ],
                  );
                } else {
                  return const SizedBox(width: 0);
                }
              },
            ),
          ),

This is my GridView for example:
 GridView.builder(
                 
                  itemCount: itemList.length,
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                                    crossAxisSpacing: 20.0,
                                    mainAxisSpacing: 12.0,
                                    //childAspectRatio: 0.7,
                                    mainAxisExtent: 250,
                                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    if (index % 2 == 0 && index < itemList.length) {
                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          ListElementWidget(data: itemList[index]),
                          (index + 1 < itemList.length)
                              ? Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                                  child: ListElementWidget(
                                      data: itemList[index + 1]),
                                )
                              : const SizedBox(
                                  width: 0,
                                ),
                        ],
                      );
                    } else {
                      return const SizedBox(width: 0);
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),

The SizedBox in GridView will leave empty space but in ListView it will not, any reasons as to why and also how to overcome this? I know you can overcome this by creating a new list with removed items and passing that to the GridView, but if the list is very large and that just slows down the app

ListView does not insert any space between its children. Each child widget takes up as much space as it needs based on its content, and they are laid out one after another.
A GridView arranges its children in a 2D grid format, with rows and columns. It automatically calculates and inserts spacing between its children based on properties like gridDelegate and crossAxisSpacing/mainAxisSpacing.
In above example with GridView decrease mainAxisExtent for remove space between items.
